# Getting error The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records when I try to delete a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Gemfile :

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

in the initializer folder I created a file aws.rb with the following code

```
AWS.config(access_key_id: '...key id...', secret_access_key: '...secret_key...')

S3_BUCKET = AWS::S3.new.buckets['my_bucket']
```

I have a file in the path :

`my_backet/uploads/391cd178-a64a-4fda-83b6-210430c34a0c/file.png`

when I try to delete a file

```
def delete_file

      key = '391cd178-a64a-4fda-83b6-210430c34a0c/file.png'

      S3_BUCKET.objects[key].delete

end
```

I get the error

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId in ImagesController#delete_file  
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: And you double-checked that you're using the right credentials, and that they're still active in the account of the bucket you're trying to access?  How did you get them?  (Did you generate them?  Did someone give them to you?)

Comment: yeah the credentials are correct, I get them from the s3 cloud, I already use the same object S3_BUCKET to presigned my upload :   `@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(
    key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}",
    success_action_status: 201,
    acl: :public_read)`

Comment: @KarenB I have this problem when I try to delete a file

Comment: Are you sure the IAM credentials have delete rights on the bucket?  I would expect a different exception for that than "InvalidAccessKeyId," but I could be wrong.

Comment: @KarenB I figure it out by using AWS.config(:s3_endpoint => '.....', ......) because I am using other thing than the default region ! thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve that by providing an s3_endpoint as parameter to my  AWS.config :

```
AWS.config(
            :s3_endpoint => '...',
            :access_key_id => '....',
            :secret_access_key => '....'
           )
```

The source that helped me : https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxVOTODBPHAEP9/Working-with-Regions

Answer (score 0):

Double check the credential initialization syntax and format. It is possible you have not specified them there correctly.

The references below indicate different syntax that the one you are using.

```
AWS.config(:access_key_id => 'KEY', :secret_access_key => 'SECRET')
```

Please see:

https://ruby.awsblog.com/blog/tag/config
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Core/Configuration.html
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aws_sdk/3.1.5/AWS/Core/Configuration

Comment: I checked them again and they are correct, I already use them to generate a signature for file upload and they work! only on delete I have this issue